# Django Restframework dj-rest-auth password reset confirm submit issue

Tags: django-rest-framework, reset-password

While trying to setup password reset process using Dj-rest-auth package. I ran into an issue getting the submit button to do the post request to rest_password_reset_confirm api endpoint. I keeping getting error message relating to 'ContentType' and $.post method only performing GET request. I took the form and everything from the demo app in dj-rest-auth [here](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/tree/master/demo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-write the ajax script in base.html to below for it to work. I also added two new div for success and failure response.

```css
<div class="form-group api-response-success" style="color: green;"></div>
  <div class="form-group api-response-error" style="color: red;"></div>
```

```js
          $().ready(function(){
            $('form.ajax-post button[type=submit]').click(function(e){
              var form = $('form.ajax-post');
              var url = form.attr('action');
              data = form.serializeArray();
              var object_with_key_value = {};
              $.map(data, function(n, i){
                object_with_key_value[n['name']] = n['value'];
               });

              $.ajax({
                'url': url,
                'type':"POST",
                'data': JSON.stringify(object_with_key_value),
                'contentType': 'application/json',
                'success': function(data){
                    $('.api-response-success').html("Password has been reset with the new password.");
                },
                'error': function(data){
                    $('.api-response-error').html("Something went wrong, please try again.");
                },
              });
              e.preventDefault();
            })
          });
```